# Prompt message doesn't show in Minibuffer when using emacs in "--daemon" mode

Tags: emacs

I am using emacs24.3.1 on Ubuntu 14.04.

I try to use emacs --daemon mode, here is what I have done:

1. From a terminal, run "emacs --daemon"
2. From another terminal, run "emacsclient -nc -a '' ", a new frame is created.
3. When I press the key "M-x", the prompt message displayed in the terminal where I run "emacs --daemon" instead of the minibuffer.

If before step 2, I run "emacs" to open a frame and **restart the server**. Then keep it opened. The minibuffer works fine.

Comment: I can't reproduce with emacs 24.3.1 on Ubuntu 12.04, using two gnome terminal instances. Please confirm whether the problem exists when running `emacs --daemon -Q` ?

Comment: I tried "emacs --daemon -Q", everything works fine. I am using emacs24-starter-kit. I think it will be a long way to go to figure out what's with the init files.

Comment: Hi @phils. thanks for your help. I found the problem. I call my toggle full screen function in the init files and that cause the daemon doesn't start properly. Comments out that line. Everything work fine now.

Comment: Good to hear. You should post the code in question in an answer, and accept it. It might help someone with a similar issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With @phils's help, I found that the problem is caused by having toggle full screen function call in the init files, then the emacs daemon can't be started properly. After remove it, everything works well.